# Automatic OTP verification not working in Android

Tags: android

I'm implementing automatic OTP verification functionality in my app, for that I refereed [this post](http://swarajsaaj.github.io/posts/reading-sms-automatically-otp-verification-android) but it is not working (i.e My Broadcast receiver's ***onReceive()*** never gets called even if OTP received). I'm testing on my Remi-2 (Android 4.4 Kitkat version) device. 
      **I think this is permission issue** **because, if I manually set "Send SMS and Read SMS" permission in my app settings it works perfectly fine**. I also have specified below permissions in my manifest file--

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"
        android:required="true">
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"
        android:required="true"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"
        android:required="true">
    </uses-permission>
```

My rest of the code is same as [this post](http://swarajsaaj.github.io/posts/reading-sms-automatically-otp-verification-android). Any help will really appreciated. Also please let me know if I can provide more information for the same. Thank you

Comment: If that device has SMS permissions in the app Settings, then that's OEM-specific. Android didn't have that feature until Marshmallow. Since your app works when you manually set the permission, then you've got everything setup correctly in your app. Apart from prompting the user to enable that, there might not be anything you can do.

Comment: @Mike M. I think you are right.. Thanks for your valuable comment..

Answer (score 1):

The `<uses-permission>` tag does not have any attribute called `android:required` as mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html)

In your MANIFEST file declare these permissions inside `<manifest>` tag:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
```

Comment: I tried your solutions.. still not working.. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Check if your permissions for this application has SMS permission enabled in your settings

Answer (score 0):

The android:required param is used when you declare a feature. Please refer this:

```
<uses-feature
  android:name="string"
  android:required=["true" | "false"]
  android:glEsVersion="integer" />
```